# SourceTree on MacOSX Sierra 10.13.x : Permission Denied at each laptop restart

Tags: android, git, bitbucket, atlassian-sourcetree

I use SourceTree with Bitbucket. Since the last updates of my MacOSx there is this error at each time I restart my laptop (when I want to push my code to my Bitbucket account of course):

```
git -c diff.mnemonicprefix=false -c core.quotepath=false -c credential.helper=sourcetree push -v --tags origin refs/heads/develop:refs/heads/develop 
Pushing to git@bitbucket.org:xxx/mobile-android.git
git@bitbucket.org: Permission denied (publickey).
fatal: Could not read from remote repository.

Please make sure you have the correct access rights
and the repository exists.
Completed with errors, see above
```

How can I do to avoid this at each restart? This problem is here since 10.12 Sierra OS version.

** UPDATE

Currently, I must do that at each restart:

1. Remove all keys in .ssh folders
2. From SourceTree remove the last connection, and create a new connection linked with my bitbucket account
3. A new key is automatically created by SourceTree
4. I copy it and I paste it on my Bitbucket settings account

Now, It's ok. But I can't understand why I need to do that now at each restart...

Thanks for your help guys!

Comment: What has the restart got to do with it exactly?

Comment: It's like the sourcetree configuration has been modified.

Comment: @anthony I have the same issue. How did you solve it?

Answer (score 0):

Apple changed the behavior of the ssh-agent in Sierra (macOS 10.12); it will no longer store keys automatically. (There's a bit more detail at https://developer.apple.com/library/content/technotes/tn2449/_index.html if you're interested.)

You can update your ~/.ssh/config file to include `AddKeysToAgent yes`. If your key has a passphrase, then it'll still prompt the first time you use that key after a restart, but otherwise it should just remember the key.

Comment: my answer below please